# Angular -Select Dropdown not loading data

Tags: angular

In Angular13 I have this code:

enum:

```
export const CHARGE_REQUIRED = [
  {
    'key': 0,
    'value': 'False'
  },
  {
    'key': 1,
    'value': 'True'
  }
]
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControlOptions, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CHARGE_REQUIRED } from 'src/app/core/enum/chargerequired';
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from "ngx-bootstrap/modal";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { StudentService } from 'src/app/feature/admin/services/student.service';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-create',
  templateUrl: './student-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student-create.component.scss']
})
export class StudentCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  createStudentForm!: FormGroup;
  isSubmitted = false;
  isLoading = false;
  chargeRequired!: any[];

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private studentService: StudentService,
    private router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chargeRequired = CHARGE_REQUIRED;
    this.createStudent();
  }

  createStudent() {
    this.createStudentForm = this.fb.group({
      RegistrationNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]],
      ChargeRequired: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  createValidate() {
    if (!this.createStudentForm.valid) {
      this.createStudentForm.markAllAsTouched();
      return;
    }
  }
  get fc() {
    return this.createStudentForm.controls;
  };

  onStudentSubmitForm() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if (this.createStudentForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.isLoading = true;

    const formData = this.createStudentForm.value;

    this.studentService.createStudent(formData).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.toastr.success(res.message);
        this.isLoading = false;
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.toastr.error(error.message);
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I have these fields: StudentRegistration and ChargeReguired as shown in the code. There is a select dropdown list for the Charge Required.

component.html:

```html
<div role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Add Student</h4>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="onClose()">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="visually-hidden">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="add-form" [formGroup]="createStudentForm" (ngSubmit)="onStudentSubmitForm()">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="RegistrationNumber">Registration Number<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='RegistrationNumber' id="RegistrationNumber" placeholder="Registration Number">
              <div *ngIf="fc['RegistrationNumber'].touched && fc['RegistrationNumber'].invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="fc['RegistrationNumber'].errors && fc['RegistrationNumber'].errors['required']">Registration Number is required!</div>
                <div *ngIf="fc['RegistrationNumber'].errors && fc['RegistrationNumber'].errors['minlength']">Registration Number cannot be less than 5 characters!</div>
                <div *ngIf="fc['RegistrationNumber'].errors && fc['RegistrationNumber'].errors['maxlength']">Registration Number cannot be more than 50 characters!</div>
                <div *ngIf="fc['RegistrationNumber'].errors && fc['RegistrationNumber'].errors['pattern']">Enter only numbers for Registration Number!</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="ChargeRequired">Charges Required<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <ng-select [items]="chargeRequired" [selectOnTab]="true" [searchable]="true" bindValue="key" bindLabel="value" placeholder="Select Charge Required" [multiple]="false" [clearable]="true" formControlName="ChargeRequired">
              </ng-select>
              <div *ngIf="fc['ChargeRequired'].touched && fc['ChargeRequired'].invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="fc['ChargeRequired'].errors && fc['ChargeRequired'].errors['required']">The field is required!</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="cancelCreate" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onClose()">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="isLoading" (click)="createValidate()"><span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
          <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the dropdown list, it doesn't load any data.

But as I did

console.log(this.chargeRequired) in OnInit, I got:

```
[
    {
        "key": 0,
        "value": "False"
    },
    {
        "key": 1,
        "value": "True"
    }
]
```

How do I sort this out?

Thank you

Comment: can you please provide a stackblitz?

Comment: Need more code snippet to reproduce the issue or provide a stackblitz

Comment: @Anna - I have updated the code with more details